# How to access a URL using Node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to create web access to sending a message using sms gateway.

I have an url like this:

```
http://162.211.84.203/sms/smsreguler.php?username=zzz&key=xxx&number=628978520815&message=asdasd
```

How do I open that url using Node.js?

Comment: look for the `request` library in npm

Answer (score 1):

One option and my preferred method is using the **axios** package.

> Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js

First **install axios** into your package.json

`npm install --save axios` or `npm i -S axios`

Then **require axios** into the appropriate file and send a get request to the appropriate URL

```
var axios = require('axios')

axios.get('http://162.211.84.203/sms/smsreguler.php?username=zzz&key=xxx&number=628978520815&message=asdasd')
      .then(function (res) {
          console.log(res);
          // ... do something with the response
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
```

This is the most I can say without seeing your deployment. Happy to provide more information depending on your circumstances.

[The docs for axios are here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Answer (score 0):

Official docs for [`request`](https://github.com/request/request#table-of-contents)

```
npm install request --save //install it first

var request = require('request'); //require somewhere and use
var url = 'http://162.211.84.203/..'; //omitted for brevity

request(url, function(err, response, body) {
    // Do more stuff with 'body' here
});
```